# Sending file through ssh2, scp

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I need to send a copy from server1 to server2 using ssh2. Both are using ubuntu, and I'm trying sending it with the scp command:

```
scp test.txt userName@server2_direction:/folder_destination
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
test.txt: No such file or directory
```

I tried putting the complete url: /users/asd/my_user/folder/test.txt, but it doesn't work either.

Any hints?

Comment: The syntax is correct, I don't know why it wouldn't work (assuming the file exists in the current directory).

Comment: Is your complete "url" (it's not an URL btw, its just the full path to the file) just an example or does it really look like that? Linux is case sensitive also, just in case the file is named like text.TXT or Test.txt. If the file is in your home directory or subfolder to your home dir, try ~/subdir/filename as path.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the wrong directory on the source computer. Check if there is `test.txt` in the current directory.

```
$ ls -l test.txt
```

Comment: Does the problem exist with other files too? Or only with this?

Comment: Are you sure the full path is correct? Type `pwd` in the directory where test.txt is located and copy paste it. Also note the case sensitive file system as mentioned in my comment to your question.